# Script to prevent nested root shells (POSIX)

Tags: shell, posix

Script to prevent **nested root** shells shall do exactly as said, plus some niceties like an error message when someone runs it with some argument/option.

---

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -o nounset; set -o errexit

error()
{
    printf >&2 '%b\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

is_root()
{
    [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
}

start_root_shell()
{
    exec sudo -s
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    error "Usage of $(basename "$0") script:\n" \
    'Starts a root shell, no argument accepted.'
fi

if is_root; then
    error 'You are already superuser!'
fi

start_root_shell
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the things I like in this script:

- Good use of the shell options to find simple mistakes.  That's the first thing I do in my shell scripts.
- Good error reporting - correctly using the error stream and exit status
- Good use of quoted strings.  You didn't miss the tricky one in `$(basename "$0")`.
- Everything is laid out well - it's clear and easy to read.

The observations I have are generally quite minor.

---

I don't see why we have two separate commands here:

> ```
> set -o nounset; set -o errexit
> ```

It's simpler to write

```
set -o nounset  -o errexit
```

---

We're using an undefined conversion here:

> ```
> printf >&2 '%b\n' "$@"
> ```

`%b` isn't among the [conversions specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05).  I think that `%s` should be fine here, if we change the single use of `\n` into a separate string argument (and this neatly fixes an obscure bug if the command file-name contains `\`):

```
    error "Usage of $(basename "$0") script:" \
          ''  \
          'Starts a root shell, no argument accepted.'
```

---

`is_root` and `start_root_shell` each contain a single command and are used just once, so the benefit of using functions is debatable.  I'd lean towards inlining them, perhaps with a comment.

---

## Modified version

The only change I'd insist upon if accepting this code would be to use a specified, portable conversion in the `printf`.  The rest is just style.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o nounset -o errexit

error()
{
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
then
    error "Usage of $(basename "$0") script:" \
          '' \
          'Starts a root shell, no argument accepted.'
fi

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
then
    error 'You are already superuser!'
fi

# Start the root shell
exec sudo -s
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [Toby Speight's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/287641/104270) which pointed me in the right direction, I myself have a point to make.

---

It would be handy if a user of the script had the possibility to change the actual root command, be it `sudo -s`, `sudo -i`, or even without `sudo`, directly using `su`.

The second change concerns the check for `sudo` being installed, which does not guarantee the user can use it, but at least something.

This (likely final) code is published on GitHub under MIT license.

### Modified code incl. some other minor changes

```bash
#!/bin/sh

#------------------------------------------------------------
#--      Become root, but prevent nested root shells       --
#--           Code language: POSIX shell script            --
#--            Copyright: 2023 Vlastimil Burian            --
#--             Bugs: info@vlastimilburian.cz              --
#--             GitHub: burian.work/root-shell             --
#--                      License: MIT                      --
#--                 Version: 1.1 (stable)                  --
#--                 Released: 2023-Nov-21                  --
#------------------------------------------------------------

# You may customize this to e.g.: "sudo -i", or even "su",...
readonly root_command="sudo -s"

set -o nounset -o errexit

error()
{
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

usage()
{
    error \
        "Usage of $(basename "$0") script:" \
        "" \
        "Starts a root shell using '$root_command', no argument accepted."
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
then
    usage
fi

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
then
    error "You are already superuser."
fi

if ! command -v sudo >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    printf >&2 '%s\n\n' "'sudo' is required by this script."
    usage
fi

# start root shell
exec $root_command
```